# Difficulty in implementing a one to one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to update the profile of a user, however, I am getting an ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 6, expected 1)): The relation between the user model and user profile model is one-to-one

application_controllers.rb

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  
  helper_method :current_user, :logged_in?
  
  def current_user 
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    
  end
end
```

```rb
 def create 
    @user_profile = UserProfile.new(user_profile_params)
    
    @user_profile.user_id = current_user.id
    
    if @user_profile.save 
      format.html {redirect_to home_index_path, notice:"Account created successfully" }
    else
       flash.now.alert = "Oops, couldn't create account. Please make sure you are using a valid email and password and try again."
      format.html { render :new }
    end
  end

private
  
  def user_profile_params 
    params.require(:first_name, :other_name, :last_name, :phonemumber, :email, :seller_id)
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is on this line:

```rb
  def user_profile_params 
    params.require(:first_name, :other_name, :last_name, :phonemumber, :email, :seller_id)
  end
```

You should use either:

```rb
  def user_profile_params 
    params.require(:user_profile).permit(:first_name, :other_name, :last_name, :phonemumber, :email, :seller_id)
  end
```

or

```rb
  def user_profile_params 
    params.permit(:first_name, :other_name, :last_name, :phonemumber, :email, :seller_id)
  end
```

Depends on data you are getting from the form. And btw. there is a typo in `:phonemumber` should probably be `:phonenumber`.

Comment: I am still getting this error 
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 6, expected 1)):  What can it be?